# How can i put space between my dropdown menu in html&css

Tags: html, css

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #eca02e;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}
  
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
  
  .dropdown-sinif {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-sinif a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-sinif {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Matematik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Fizik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the html code

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Matematik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Fizik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the CSS code

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #eca02e;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}
  
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
  
  .dropdown-sinif {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-sinif a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-sinif {
    display: block;
  }
```

I tried margin bottom,left,right but could not manage to do it.I guess i made something wrong and it is better to use ul and li to this kind of content ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where do you want to add space? between the a tags (9,10,11,12) or between the two buttons?

Comment: between buttons

Comment: snippet updated to add space between buttons

Answer (score 1):

make your a tags display:block and then add margin-bottom.  add margin-left or margin-right to .dropdown to add space between your buttons

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #eca02e;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}
  
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right:200px;
}
  
  .dropdown-sinif {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-sinif a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  a{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  }
  
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-sinif {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Matematik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Fizik</button>
        <div class="dropdown-sinif">
        <a href="#">9.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">10.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">11.Sınıf</a>
        <a href="#">12.Sınıf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```